# Method in dialog executed before method in commandLink which shows the dialog

Tags: jsf, dialog, popup, commandlink

I have an issue with JSF pop up window:

this is the code that calls popup:

```
<p:commandLink id="emmiSumTableColumnValue5YesLink"
                                    type="button" value="Yes"
                                    rendered="#{summary.mE.exist}"
                                    action="#{UserBean.inokeProgramms()}"
                                    oncomplete="PF('view').show();">
                                    <f:param name="UserCode"
                                        value="#{summary.mE.accessCodeId}" />
                                </p:commandLink>
```

This is dialog 'view' which should calls after commandLink action executed:

```
<p:dialog closable="true" modal="true" closeOnEscape="true" 
       resizable="false" appendToBody="true" header="#{pocMsgBundle.title}"
       widgetVar="view" draggable="false" dynamic="true" height="500" width="600">
<p:scrollPanel mode="native" style="height:500px">
<p:dataTable id="eMTable" scrollable="true" value="#{UserBean.selectedProgram}" var="sProgram" emptyMessage="No data available.">
<p:column>
<p:panelGrid columns="1">
<p:column>
<h:outputText id="eMTimestamp" value="#{sProgram.entryDateTime}">
<f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a" timeZone="#{UserBean.timeZone}"/>
</h:outputText>
</p:column>
<p:column>
<h:outputText id="eMText" value="#{sProgram.text}" />
</p:column>
</p:panelGrid>
</p:column>
</p:dataTable>
</p:scrollPanel>
</p:dialog>`
```

Method from dialog `UserBean.selectedProgram` calls earlier than `UserBean.inokeProgramms()` in commandLink action.

how can I fix this?

Thanks.

**SOLUTION**
I added ID for dialog and use update action in commandLink block for dialog ID

Comment: That is expected behavior. You might want to check out Ajax. http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/basic.xhtml

Comment: update fixed this problem

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer and accept it to help others.

Comment: I added ID for dialog and use update action in commandLink block for dialog ID